# How do I transfer this local server API to a web API to deploy my app in heroku?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I have these code for a Chat App and it is only working in Local Server

I have already tried the following. Calling io() without any path arguments.

```
 // Client Side Code
     socket = io();
    socket.connect({ query: `username=${props.username}` })
```

The above didnt work. The app runs but does not show other user's messages.

```
 // Client Side Code
    socket = io('http://myherokuapp:3001', { query: 
     `username=${props.username}` }).connect();
```

Neither did the above code work. The app crashed on this one.

Here is my actual source code:

```
  // Server Side Code
 const express = require("express");
 const path = require("path");
 const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
 const app = express();
 const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");
 const io = require("socket.io");

 const server = http.createServer(app);
 const socketIo = io(server);

 app.use(cors());

 app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('./public/index.html'));
 });

 socketIo.on('connection', socket => {
   const username = socket.handshake.query.username;
   console.log(`${username} connected`);

   socket.on('client:message', data => {
     console.log(`${data.username}: ${data.message}`);
     socket.broadcast.emit('server:message', data);
   });

   socket.on('disconnect', () => {
     console.log(`${username} disconnected`);
   });
 });

 server.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(` ==> API server now on port ${PORT}!`);
 });



 // Client Side Code
     socket = io('http://localhost:3001', { query: 
 `username=${props.username}` }).connect();

     socket.on('server:message', message => {
       addMessage(message);
     });

     socket.emit('client:message', messageObject);

     addMessage(messageObject);
```

I expect the chat app to be working same as it does in localhost.

Comment: You deployed your app on Heroku which means that it's no longer accessible via `localhost` but rather via the web address given to you by Heroku.

Comment: I understand that but I need to know in codes how to make this work for heroku. I tried to use      

         socket = io('http://myherokuapp:3001', { query: 
            `username=${props.username}` }).connect();

But this did not work.